# push binded data into object doesn't work?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

demo and code here : http://plnkr.co/edit/9tSbJBAE8qPr7DKeGUla?p=preview

I try to make my tab dynamic by allowing the users to add more tab, but it seem can't grab the name, I wonder I'd bind it with ngmodel.

```
<input type="text" ng-model="NewTabName"/>
<button ng-click="addTab()">Add</button>
```

js

```
$scope.addTab = function(){
    $scope.tabs.push({
        "name" : $scope.NewTabName
    });
    $scope.NewTabName = "";
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace:

```
$scope.tabs.push({
      "name" : $scope.NewTabName
  });
$scope.NewTabName = "";
```

With:

```
$scope.tabs.push({
      "name" : this.NewTabName //Use this instead of $scope
  });
this.NewTabName = ""; //Use this instead of $scope
```

The problem is scope inheritance, the `NewTabName` property is created on your **child scope** of $scope. By using `this`, I can access **the correct scope** that triggered the event.

[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/vu2IUWtdqkutMhPgMFqW?p=preview)

Comment: what is the parent scope of my parent? the 'tabs'?

Comment: @user3398172: the parent of your controller's scope is root scope.

Answer (score 0):

Updated plunkr here: http://plnkr.co/edit/OpVWtmt0k3LKsMPbGUIY?p=preview

You have to bind `ng-model` to a property of some object not the object itself. Otherwise it (i.e. angular) may (and in this case is) creating an object `NewTabName` in other scope than you think it is.

```
$scope.addTab = function(){
    $scope.tabs.push({
        "name" : $scope.NewTabName.text
    });
    $scope.NewTabName.text = "";
}

<input type="text" ng-model="NewTabName.text"/>
<button ng-click="addTab()">Add</button>
```

Comment: .text is a default property or new created one?

Comment: created. at the beginning of the controller: `$scope.NewTabName = {text: ''};`